# Android:How to make sure popup appears next to button?

Tags: android, location, popupwindow

Using PopupWindow.showAtLocation()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation(android.view.View, int, int, int)

How do I use that function to make sure the popup window always appears to the right of the a button?

I have the following scenarios:

**Collapsed View:**

[image]

**Expanded View:**

[image]

Comment: How are you doing it now and how is it showing up with the code you have?

Comment: @codeMagic I'm doing it using a static value: mWindow.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.CENTER, anchor.getWidth()+50, 0); the problem is that it doesn't work in collapsed view because what is actually happening is that the menu is shifted to the left.

Answer (score 0):

The [NewQuickAction](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction) is probably what you need.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the one I used but that one shows the dialog at the top or bottom not the right of the button.